# How do I reference a picture box from a different class to a timer event method

Tags: c#, timer

So basically, I am trying to make an amateur mini RPG game after my first year in a computer science high school, and I am trying to make an attack, where a dagger (pictureBox2) comes out slowly from a character, and then comes back in. I have managed to make the dagger go out and then in, but my problem is that once I tried putting in a different class, I was unable to pass the picture box into the timer event, as both my `object sender` and `ElapsedEventArgs e`  were rendered "unused" [as you can see, "`sender`" and `e` are unused here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KbDq.png)
but when I remove `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox weapon` from parameters, they go back to being "used" aka. my Elapsed event actually works

So could anyone please explain me how to use a Picture Box inside of a timer event from another class

P.S. I am using System.Timers.Timer, the third photo should show how I set the timer [my Timer Set Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkMBk.png)

Comment: In the future, it's better to post your code as TEXT in part of your post instead of linking to images of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the signature of your Elapsed() event as it should be with only "sender,e" in the parameters.

Change your line that wires up the event to:

```
timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;
```

Then cast "sender" to a Timer, and chase that by casting "SynchronizingObject" to a PictureBox:

```
private static void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    PictureBox weapon = (PictureBox)timer.SynchronizingObject;
    AttackMov(weapon));
}
```